# VirtualBox vdi not growing over 32 GB, NS_ERROR_CALL_FAILED when trying to delete snapshot

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, snapshot

I am running VirtualBox 5.2.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit. The quest system is Win 10 64-bit. 
At some point guest went jammed because vdi disk of dynamic size 100GB refused to grow over 32GB. I have googled that it may happen when snapshots exist. Not sure if this is true, anyway I have tried to delete the only snapshot I have. Anyway it is unsuccessful:

```
:~$ VBoxManage snapshot "machine" delete "snapshot"
Deleting snapshot 'updated, clean' (fdef5e6e-52cf-451c-abb2-64016c34cb42)
0%...10%...20%...30%...
Progress object failure: NS_ERROR_CALL_FAILED
VBoxManage: error: Snapshot operation failed
VBoxManage: error: Code NS_ERROR_CALL_FAILED (0x800706BE) - Call to remote object failed (extended info not available)
VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleSnapshot(HandlerArg*)" at line 539 of file VBoxManageSnapshot.cpp
```

What can be done to suppress both the problems (expanding disk over 32GB and deleting snapshots)?

Comment: Clone the virtual disk then expand the new virtual disk.  If the machine is suspended this won’t work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it appeared that failure on snapshot delete and disk grow limitation were two independent problems.

1) snapshot delete - suggestion by Ramhound worked as a charm. I have received a cloned vm with no shapshots.

2) disk growing stuck up - stupid me; I had a regular NTFS partition of 32 GB, Windows Recovery Partition adjacent to it and muuuuch unallocated space at the rest of the drive. So the problem was not about vdi itself at all. I have easily reorganized the virtual disk with [AOMEI Partition Assistant](https://www.aomeitech.com/aomei-partition-assistant.html).

BTW I have made copy of my VM to try two approaches:
- get rid of the recovery partition and then resize the working one,
- move recovery partition to the end of the disk and then resize the working one.
Both the ways give the desired output, ie much space on the drive and moderate size of vdi